# How to debug using QEMU in Debian 10

Tags: c, gdb, debian, qemu, debian-buster

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

That's how I compile it

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -O0 -g3 main.c
```

I started the `a.out` like this:

```
qemu-aarch64-static -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -singlestep -g 1234 ./a.out
```

And then I started `gdb`

```
$ gdb-multiarch -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) set sysroot /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/
(gdb) target remote :1234
Remote debugging using :1234
Reading symbols from /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
0x0000004000814040 in ?? ()
   from /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x76c: file main.c, line 4.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (Remote target) exited normally]
```

My question: why `gdb` didn't stop on `main` entrance and program just finished without any break? What am I do wrong?

I've repeated these steps on Ubuntu 20.04 and everything works fine. To be fair, I use ubuntu for a long time and could just forget what I did before, but Debian is fresh.

**Versions info:**

- OS: `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`
- QEMU: `qemu-aarch64 version 3.1.0 (Debian 1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u8)`
- GDB: `GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1`
- GCC: `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Debian 8.3.0-2) 8.3.0`

Comment: It seems to be a bug in `qemu-user-static` package in debian 10. I've downloaded latest version from https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/releases/tag/v6.1.0-6 and everything works fine. I anyone else confirm the bug, I'll close the question.